# check if data exist while inserting data

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

How to insert a record to a table if there is no data exist of same type

```
insert into  user_table (userid, active,contid) values ('AAA',1,1);
insert into  user_table (userid, active,contid) values ('ABA',1,2);
          
        INSERT INTO new_table(userid,isactive)
SELECT userid,1
  FROM user_table where contid=1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid
                     FROM new_table
                    WHERE contid=1
                  )
```

i need to copy data from one table1 to table2 if table2 doesnt have the same data. if data exist just skip and dont make any insert. I am getting  "SQL command not properly ended" error with the above query

Comment: Please do not edit answers into your question that substantially changes the question and invalidates (some) existing answers. If you have clarifications to the question then keep the existing code and add a new section below with the clarification; or, if you have a follow-up question then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exisrs clause should have another condition.

You need to check if  a active userid already exists too

```
INSERT INTO new_table(userid,isactive)
SELECT userid,1
  FROM user_table WHERE contid=1
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM new_table
                    WHERE user_table.userid = new_table.userid AND contid=1
                  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO new_table dst
USING ( SELECT userid, contid
        FROM   user_table
        WHERE  contid = 1) src
ON src.userid = dst.userid AND src.contid = dst.contid
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (userid, isactive) VALUES (src.userid, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `insert` query has two `where` keywords; the 2nd one should've been `and`:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (userid, isactive)
   SELECT userid, 1
     FROM user_table
    WHERE     contid = 1
          AND NOT EXISTS               --> AND instead of WHERE
                 (SELECT userid
                    FROM new_table
                   WHERE contid = 1);
```

---

Also, perhaps a `minus` set operator would do as well:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (userid, isactive)
   SELECT u.userid, 1
     FROM user_table u
   MINUS
   SELECT n.userid, 1
     FROM new_table n;
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the `where` keyword twice. I'm sharing the code below.

```
INSERT INTO new_table(userid,isactive)
SELECT userid,1 
FROM user_table 
WHERE contid=1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid FROM new_table WHERE contid=1 )
```

Comment: This fixes the syntax error but will only add the row when `new_table` contains no rows where `contid=1` regardless of the `userid`; it does not correlate the `EXISTS` sub-query to compare the `userid` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` to get only users that are not exists on table new_table using the condition `new_table.userid is null` :

```
INSERT INTO new_table(userid, isactive)
SELECT u.userid, 1
FROM user_table u
LEFT JOIN new_table n on n.userid = u.userid
where u.contid=1 and u.active = 1 and n.userid is null
```